# Is it possible to host more than one site in IIS 8.5?

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

This is not my strong suit, all help will be appreciate it.

I'm hosting a site that is using an SSL certificate, I have created a second site that dont use SSL certificates, but I'm not able to get it to diplay it in the browser. I just get this error:

The domain rd.orders.com is not assigned to a site.
Please verify that everything is set up correctly.

I have done a research and I cant find anything related to this type of issue.

Comment: If you did any research you should know posting your IIS configuration in a question is the very first step to allow others to help. `<sites>` tag in `applicationHost.config` contains the key information for meaningful discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS supports hosting multiple websites on a single server, you can assign a unique IP address to each Web site, designate a non-standard TCP port number for a Web site, or use host headers. Of the three methods, it is more common to use host headers than to assign unique IP addresses to Web sites or to use non-standard TCP port numbers.

And if you want to configure a host header for a site, you can perform this procedure by using the user interface (UI), by running Appcmd.exe commands in a command-line window, by editing configuration files directly, or by writing WMI scripts

For more details, I recommend that you could refer to this document: [Configure a Host Header for a Web Site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-r2-and-2008/cc753195(v=ws.10)).